# Add only 10 records using Java in Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, limit

I am making application in Java using Netbeans. I want that admin can only add 10 users record and after 10 users added in database the Admin not able to add more users(my idea is that buttons are disable after 10 users addition). I am using MySQL for record saving.

Comment: what is the problem? you want to restrict the records on MySQL table?

Comment: I want the GUI that shows message that you entered 10 users. database limit is not infront of Admin.

Comment: You have to write logic to check 10 users created by admin. I do not understand the question completely. can you explain it bit?

Comment: i want professionally look in my application that if (Admin)you want to add more users you can buy this application or upgrade to pro version etc,, etc

Comment: how will you make an application, which someone would buy, if you are not able to implement this simple logic?

Comment: I believe you could just count the records and decide whether the user can or cannot insert more records. What have you tried so far?

Comment: to your problem: look in the table if there are 10 rows inserted by this user ( you hopefully have a column where the user who inserted this record is stored), if yes -> disable the button

Comment: @griFlo  I am student not professional. so I need professional look in my application. I am not selling this app.

Comment: @griFlo yes I made same logic but I am bit confused about query or if conditions

Comment: @fzprog okay, but you have not asked a specific question. what is your exact problem? what have you tried?

Comment: @fzprog show your logic here, we may help you in that.

Comment: all the data retrieved using resultset rs variable and rs  gets 10 records from the database then buttons disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire a count query on your table. And use the resultset to restrict(validate, records<=10) before the app(client) enters a new value. Or put constraint in the schema design itself.

Comment: I am not too much good in database that's why I am asking question here. I want about java code that query needed or only if conditions works here @Shubham Chaurasia